# How to determine if the field is enabled or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, jquery-selectors

I have the following script, to display an "*" beside any required fields:-

```
$('input[data-val-required]').after('<span class='my-class'>*</span>')
```

But can i define extra filtering so that the "*" will only be displayed if the following is true:-

1. the field is an Input field with data-val-required ?
2. the field is not disabled , or is not read-only?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

[:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

[Has Attribute Selector [name]](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

```
$('input[data-val-required]:not([disabled],[readonly])').after('<span class="my-class">*</span>')
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/jUcjC/)

---

**Update After OP's Comment**

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/jUcjC/1)

[Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('input[data-val-required]:not([disabled],[readonly],[type="hidden"])').after('<span class="my- class">*</span>')
```

Comment: i tried adding [hidden] inside the not([disabled],[readonly],[hidden]), but the * will be displayed beside any hidden field, can you advice how i can also exclude hidden fields from the script ?

Comment: @johnG Are you talking about  `<input type="hidden"/>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$('input[data-val-required]').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':disabled')) {
        $(this).after('<span class="my-class">*</span>')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()`:

```
$('input').filter(function() {  
    return $(this).data('val-required') && !$(this).prop('disabled') && !$(this).prop('readonly');
}).after('<span class="my-class">*</span>');
```